# How to un-encrypt a single encrypted field from a file in Linux (openssl, rsa key)

Tags: linux, openssl, rsa, public-key-encryption

I have a csv file that I receive every day on Linux.  The file itself is NOT encrypted as a whole, but one of the fields is, so it looks something like this:

*data, data, data, **encrypted_data**, data, etc*

I have an RSA key for the decryption, and right now I am parsing the file one line at a time, cutting the encrypted field, decrypting it with openssl, and putting it back in the line, like this:

```
      ###cut out the encrypted field into a variable
    INFIELD=`echo $DATALINE | cut -d"," -f10`

      ###decrypt the field into another variable
    OUTFIELD=`echo $INFIELD | base64 --decode | openssl rsautl -inkey $SCRIPTFILES/MyKey.rsa -decrypt`

      ###swap the decrypted value into the original line and append to a temp file
    echo $DATALINE | awk -v outfield=$OUTFIELD '{$10 = outfield;print}' FS=, OFS=, >> $DATAPATH/$TEMPFILE
```

This works, but it is **AMAZINGLY** slow...like it takes 4-5 hours to process 600,000 rows.  Is there a faster way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would probably be a good guess that spawning 6–7 brand new processes for every single line is the slowest part, even more so than the actual RSA calculations. Note that each instance of `` ` ` `` is also a subprocess (even though it's still internal to the shell and not as heavy as executing a fully external tool), and each `echo | ...` is yet another subprocess. (From what I've heard, the recent Melt/Spectre mitigations make this much worse than it would already be otherwise.)

So the faster way is to write your script in some other language which can perform decryption, decoding and everything else *in-process*. (I.e. just about any language that is not a "shell" and does not rely on invoking tools from /usr/bin.)

For example, Python has the 'Cryptodome' and 'cryptography' modules, Perl has 'CryptX' and Ruby outright has an 'OpenSSL' module. (Other languages are also available.) And of course, pretty much all of them can split comma-separated lines and decode Base64 without any external help as well.

---

I don't know at this moment what specific format is used by OpenSSL's rsautl and how to feed it into e.g. the Cryptodome library, but the general idea is:

```
require 'base64'
require 'openssl'

pkey = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(File.read("MyKey.rsa"))

while line = STDIN.gets()
    fields = line.chomp.split(",")
    fields[9] = Base64.decode64(fields[9])
    fields[9] = pkey.private_decrypt(fields[9])
    puts fields.join(",")
end
```

Comment: Unfortunately, my server has an older version of Python / pyCrypto that does not support importing RSA keys, but this led me down some fascinating roads in Python, which I am learning anyway.

As for my original issue, I ended up using a Unix only approach to split the incoming file into 15 pieces and running them in parallel.  Cut my run time down to about 30 minutes...still not great, but acceptable.

Comment: ...just how old is it? (And note that pyCrypto as a whole is dead; it has been replaced by pyCryptodome.) Does it have python-cryptography instead?